# Setting Content Root Path for .NET 6 app hosted as a windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an API build with .NET 6 that I would like to host as a Windows Service. For that, I followed the official docs and added the below code to my Program.cs:

```cs
var options = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);


builder.Host.UseWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = "Service Name";
});
```

Now I want to build this app into a single executable, self-contained, for that, I run the following command:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true /p:IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract=true --self-contained true
```

That works all fine. Now to create and run a service I'm using the below:

```
New-Service -Name $serviceName -BinaryPathName "$exePath --contentRoot $contentRootPath" -DisplayName $displayName -Description $description -StartupType $startupType
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't change the content root path and appsettings.json is not read. When I try to run the service, the content root path is still set to C:\WINDOWS\TEMP.net\monitor.API\ot3bwp1B__+k8mUZcxQc6zWIACPmScw=\

Any idea how can I set the content root path so it's poinitng to the folder with executable?

Comment: In order to fix your Windows service's content root path issue, ensure you publish the app as a single executable with embedded content, then register the service with the correct paths (including --contentRoot argument) and access content using `IHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath` in your code. If problems persist, double-check paths, environment variables, and consider troubleshooting approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, but I was able to fix it by providing an additional appsettings.json file by doing this:

```cs
string processDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.ProcessPath);

if (WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService())
{
    Log.Information("Adding new json config");
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(processDirectory, "appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

    Log.Information("app settings json: {0}", Path.Combine(processDirectory, "appsettings.json"));
}
```

This solved the problem for me, and the appsettings in now read from an additional location.

I had to do the same for each location that was pointing to ContentRootPath like my sqlLite db file location as well.